# Intefacing a PIC Mircocontroller (PIC16F84A) to two stepper motors

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor, interface

I am a neewbie here so don't cush me yet but I have a question concering stepper motors and Microcontrollers (more specificaly PIC16F84A). Does anyone know how to Inteface these two devices? 
Steppers - http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9238
Microcontroller - http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010230
Thanks in advance - James

Comment: The PIC16F84A is a dinosaur.  Why start by learning an obsolete chip? http://www.finitesite.com/d3jsys/16F628.html

Comment: @markrages ahahaahaha...thanks man...I will be sure to try it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10267

You will need to connect the Direction and Step pins to I/O pins on the microcontroller.